# Trigger function on click for hangman game

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JavaScript and have been trying to code up this Hangman game, but am running into issues. What I have to far is the following:

My HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div id="placeHolder">_ _ _ _ _ _</div>
    <div id="gamestatus"></div>
    <input type="text" size="1" id="letterGuess" maxlength="1">
    <button id="button" onclick="guess()">Press to start</button>
</div>
```

My JavaScript:

```
var dictionary = ['music', 'mountain', 'forest', 'florida', 'sweden', 'golf'];
var wordUsed, input, placeHolder; 

function startGame()
{
    placeHolder = "";
    var totalGuesses = 10;
    wordUsed = dictionary[Math.floor(Math.random() * dictionary.length)];
    console.log(wordUsed);

    var buttonText = document.getElementById("button").innerHTML = "Guess";

    for(var i = 0; i < wordUsed.length; i++)
    {
        placeHolder += "_ ";
    }

    document.getElementById("placeHolder").innerHTML = placeHolder;
    document.getElementById("gamestatus").innerHTML = "Game is in progress.";

}

function guess()
{
    var correctGuess = false;
    var ip = document.getElementById("letterGuess");
    input = ip.value;

    for(var i = 0; i < wordUsed.length; i++)
    {
        if(input == wordUsed.substring(i, i + 1))
        {
            correctGuess = true;
            placeHolder = placeHolder.substring(0, i) + input + placeHolder.substring(i + 1, placeHolder.length + 1);
            document.getElementById("placeHolder").innerHTML = placeHolder;
        }
    }
    if(!correctGuess)
    {
        totalGuesses--;
    }
    if(placeHolder == wordUsed)
    {
        alert("You WIN!");
    }
    if(totalGuesses == 0)
    {
        alert("You LOSE!")
        startGame();
    }
}
startGame();
document.getElementById("button").onclick = guess;
```

So the code is correctly selecting a word and placing the correct amount of underscores in places of the letters; but nothing happens when I run my code. I might've over-looked something really simple and would really appreciate if someone could point out what is wrong with the code/logic.

Also, any other tips on how to improve the code/logic will be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last line in your code:

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = letterGuess;
```

You have not declared `letterGuess()` as a function. You probably want something like this:

```
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", guess);
```

This will execute your `guess()` function on every click on the Button. In addition you can/should remove the `onclick=""` attribute from the `<button>`

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vt3pzk9v/) that works. Is your html set up correctly and do you actually load the script?

Your html should look something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
    <!-- your game html -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

*If `letterGuess` was just a typo, please `console.log()` something in your `guess()` function, to make sure it's being executed after clicking the button.*

Comment: I corrected the letterGuess-mistake, and removed the onclick="" from <button>. Still not getting anything from pressing the button @the-f

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a function called `letterGuess`, but you're calling it on click. Changing that call to `guess` will get you somewhere

Comment: Edited it, that was a mistake. Didnt fix the issue, though. @kwphl

Comment: I may not understand the problem you are having... I pasted your code into a pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vKmVVw and when I add a correct letter to the text box and press 'Guess' it is placing the letter on the lines as expected.

Comment: Yeah, that worked for me too not - I ended up having a missing semi colon. However, the spaces between the letters gets messed up when a correct letter is entered; preventing the user from being able to see the "You WIN"-message. Any clues on how to fix that? @kwphl

Comment: Try moving var totalGuesses=10 to the top with your other global variables.

Comment: @LearningJS888 using substring to reset the placeholder is going to be pretty tough because you are not accounting for the ' '(space) characters in the placeholder. Those are affecting the length of the placeholder, so if you change `"_ "` to `"_"` the game works. 

Now, it doesn't look as good, but It might be easier to just take that spaces out and throw some letter-spacing in with css http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vKmVVw

I'll take a stab at helping you with the js math if you dont want to solve it this way

Answer (score 0):

Correct your `Totalguesses` to be a global variable. It is local to the `startGame()` function.

It is working fine, just the guess letter needs to be in lowercase.

Working JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/k6xuc4vz/)

Comment: I moved it to be global. But, the JS fiddle is not working - looks like you might've posted my version (the broken one) as I still see totalGuesses as a local variable @Ransher.singh